# add cxf jar file in maven project?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, cxf

I need to add **cxf-core**, **cxf-frontend** ext. file in the project. I am trying to add these using maven dependency in pom.xml but it didn't work and version number is getting be red when it is added.

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-core:2.6.2 not found.

I also tried to add using external .jar libraries. The IDE is **Intellij IDEA**.

Answer (score 1):

2.6.2 worked for me, I used Eclipse to create a new maven project and pasted in your dependency. It worked, fetched the required jars and give me this dependency hierarchy.

[image: dependency hierarchy]